# How to create beans in .txt?

Tags: java, spring

I have a task. I need to define a custom bean definition. For example, define my beans in a txt file and then retrieve them through ApplicationContext in Spring Boot. I have no idea how to do it. Maybe someone can help me?

I created a class:
@Component
public class Person {

```
private String name;
private int age;
```

}

created beans.txt

personBean1=com.example.Person
personBean2=com.example.Person

@Configuration
public class CustomBeanConfig implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("beans.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parts = line.split("=");

            if (parts.length == 2) {
                String beanName = parts[0].trim();
                String className = parts[1].trim();

                registerBean(registry, beanName, className);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void registerBean(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry, String beanName, String className) {
    try {
        Class<?> beanClass = Class.forName(className);
        GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        beanDefinition.setBeanClass(beanClass);

        registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

@SpringBootApplication
public class BookShopApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(BookShopApplication.class, args);

    Person person1 = context.getBean("personBean1", Person.class);
    Person person2 = context.getBean("personBean2", Person.class);

    System.out.println(person2);
    System.out.println(person1);
}
```

}

and have this error:  No bean named 'personBean1' available

Comment: Are you planning to define your own format? That's no simple task. You'll need your ApplicationContext implementation (same way we have `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`).

Comment: Yes, I need to define my own format. 
But can I retrieve beans using AplicatonContext getBean method?

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to implement that. And it's not easy. And I don't see why you'd want to when you already have XML and annotation based approaches.

Comment: I have a  task. And it should't be a big application, but with couple beans.

Comment: Doesn't matter how big the application is. You'll need to parse the format, extract the entries into bean definitions, manage dependencies, instantiate beans, invoke post processors, etc., etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. First solution. You can use same approach as with .xml config files, but rewrite BeanDefinitionReader. You will have configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource(value = "classpath:config.txt", reader = MyCustomBeanDefinitionReader.class)
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

And custom BeanDefinitionReader:

```
public class MyCustomBeanDefinitionReader extends AbstractBeanDefinitionReader {

    public MyCustomBeanDefinitionReader(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        super(registry);
    }

    @Override
    public int loadBeanDefinitions(final Resource resource) throws BeanDefinitionStoreException {
        try {
            //take all you need from config.txt here
            String[] config = readConfig(resource.getFile()); // will return [person1='com.example.MyBean', 'person2=com.example.MyBean']

            BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = getRegistry();
            for (int i = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
                //get name and class
                String[] split = config[i].split("=");
                String beanName = split[0];
                String beanClass = split[1];

                //register bean definition
                GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
                beanDefinition.setBeanClassName(beanClass);
                registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, beanDefinition);
            }

            return config.length; // amount of registered beans
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new BeanDefinitionStoreException("Error while loading beans", e);
        }
    }

    public static String[] readConfig(File file) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line1 = reader.readLine();
            String line2 = reader.readLine();
            return new String[]{line1, line2};
        }
    }
}
```

config.txt:

```
person1=com.example.MyBean
person2=com.example.MyBean
```

Thats it. You will get person1 and person2.

If you have class:

```
public class MyBean {
    @Autowired
    private MyNormalService myNormalService;

    public MyNormalService getMyNormalService() {
        return myNormalService;
    }

    public void setMyNormalService(MyNormalService myNormalService) {
        this.myNormalService = myNormalService;
    }
}
```

You can test that Spring will inject your bean in this service, and all dependencies inside MyBean also will be handled by Spring.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private MyBean person1;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test " + person1 + " " + person1.getMyNormalService());
    }
}
```

You will have output im command line:

```
test com.example.MyBean@3343997b com.example.MyNormalService@5c1dc4e9
```

Note that you need to put config.txt in resources folder.

2. Another simple solution (but it will only work if you need to set some properties from config.txt file):

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyCustomBean myCustomBean() {
        String[] config = readConfig("path/to/your/config.txt");
        return new MyCustomBean(config[0], config[1]);
    }

    public static String[] readConfig(String filePath) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
            String line1 = reader.readLine();
            String line2 = reader.readLine();
            return new String[]{line1, line2};
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And should I add to my config.txt , for example,  myBean=com.example.MyBean?

Comment: no you don't need, you can write config.txt in any format you like

Comment: What is `new MyCustomBean(config[0], config[1])` supposed to do? It returns instances of `MyCustomBean` which is not what OP wants.

Comment: @f1sh this is an example, OP can return any class he wants, or even read it from config.txt

Comment: @PythonDev this example is useless if you don't show how to create beans of a specific types. Also it's not enough to just create them - beans have dependencies such as autowired fields that you need to take care of.

Comment: @f1sh in Spring IoC principle is used to manage dependencies, the idea of Spring Framework is not to take care of dependencies, in my opinion)

Comment: If I've understood the question correctly, the OP is asking how to define your own format for defining beans, the same way you'd define, eg. `<bean name="whatever" class="com.example.Something"/>`, but in a different text format.

Comment: @PythonDev I don't think you understand what your code does. You create an instance of `MyCustomBean`, nothing else. You don't create an instance of the classname defined in the config file. Your instance creation also conflicts with Spring's IoC principle since no dependencies are injected.

Comment: @f1sh you right, if he wants to manage all injections from config.txt  automatically it will be tricky

Comment: @f1sh check new solution

Comment: @Ksenia check this solution

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first solution and I think it's what I need